Rational quantities associated with a bicentric heptagon
For odd reasons of my own, I would like to create a math puzzle involving a bicentric heptagon (i.e., a 7-sided polygon which has both an inscribed and a circumscribed circle). The puzzle is to be computational (not a proof problem), and the answer must be an integer, though some AIME-style artifice is OK (i.e. I could say "such-and-such quantity can be expressed in lowest terms as $a+b\sqrt c$; give the value of $a+b+c$").
Disappointingly, there are no bicentric heptagons for which the inscribed and circumscribed circles have rational centers and radii. Are there other quantities or ratios associated with a bicentric heptagon that can be nontrivially rational?

MSE isn't here to do your research for you.

@RobArthan: What rule do you think my post violates? I am not expecting anyone to do research for me (and I am also attempting to do my own, as evidenced by the second link). But someone may have knowledge of this topic to share, which is what I thought Stack Exchange is for.

You propose an idea for a puzzle and provide no evidence that you have done any work on what the outcome of the puzzle might be. You are asking us to do all the work for you.
